# To get the values in Constructor From the method of another Class?

Tags: java, swing

I want to access the value of name and age in the constructor of the class Choose where I mentioned public Choose(){
Which are stored in GetValues method of NewP

**Choose.java**

```
class Choose {
    String Cn,Ca;
    public Choose(){
        btn.addMouseListener{
        }
    }

    public static void gtNp(string nn,string aa) {
        Cn=nn;
        Ca=aa;
    }

}
```

**NewP.java**

```
class NewP {
    Choose C1 = new Choose();

    NewP() {
       btn.addMouseListener{
           GetValues();
           Choose.gtNp(name,age);       
       }
    }

    public NewP GetValues(){
        Name=         ;
        Age=            ;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should start with basics first like classes and objects,etc.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: 1) Watch your variable naming schemes (variables should begin with a lower case), 2) Please format your code!! 3) You cant use static methods to gain access to instance variables 4) Mark instance variables as `private` and provide public *getters and setters* where necessary (non static methods)

Comment: David but my program is running without error even i declared variable with uppercase.

Can you give me link to tutorial to know more about 1]static methods 2]Instance variables 3]getters and setters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might not be getting the point of your code currently, but it's confusing in a way. There are several issues I spot.

First of all, you have a `static` method setting up the values of the `Choose` class, which should be resulting in an error, since you're accessing non-static variables from a static context. You should use getters and setters instead (or the fields directly, others might say). Using this method:

```
public static void gtNp(string nn,string aa){
    Cn=nn; //Java convention: fields and methods start with lowercase.
    Ca=aa;
}
```

Will result in the same values being shared by all the instances of `Choose` but, of course, this can be the desired behaviour. If they're instance-related, you can pass those values in the constructor:

```
public Choose(String nn, String aa){
   cn = nn; //To adapt your code to the convention, I've used lowercases here.
   ca = aa;
   btn.addMouseListener{
}
```

Either way, you'll want to add either getters or setters for those fields. You might want to check up what `setters` and `getters` are and implement them. I'll leave those as an excercise for you.

Here are some basic links to help you:

- [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)
- [What's an object?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) (In this one, you'll want to check up the concept of *Encapsulation*)
- [What is a Class?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)
- [Object-Oriented programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)

Comment: Thnxz for the basic links. But still confused about it.
Can you provide me more links which will clear my concepts related to object,method calling from constructor and using values of other class in constructor?

Comment: I've added two new links. One for the base of Oracle's Java tutorial and the other one to the class tutorial. I suggest you read everything from zero and go up.